# data show in RecycleView but when i want to count size of list show null (android)

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview

I have a question about list. I have a list that save more than one data. and then, when I run my apps it work and show the data. but when I debug  and want to check the size of my list just show 0 of size. what is the problem?
please help.

this is my code :

```
 query.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                for (com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    SisaKendaraanModel sisaModel = postSnapshot.getValue(SisaKendaraanModel
                                    if (//somecondition) {
                                        if (//somecondition) {
                                            kendaraanModel.add(kendaraan);
                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                        } else {
                                           kendaraanModel.remove(kendaraan);
                                           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        if (//somecondition) {
                                            kendaraanModel.add(kendaraan);
                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                        } else {
                                           kendaraanModel.remove(kendaraan);
                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (//somecondition) {
                                    kendaraanModel.add(kendaraan);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                } else {
                                    kendaraanModel.remove(kendaraan);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }

            } else {
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });
    long sizeKendaraanModel = kendaraanModel.size(); // it show 0

    adapter = new MenuHasilPencarianAdapter(MenuHasilPencarian.this, kendaraanModel, tanggalSewaPencarian, tanggalKembaliPencarian, jumlahKendaraanPencarian);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my debug result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you are making asynchronous call `addValueEventListener` . your code below is going to call just after setting listener.

```
long sizeKendaraanModel = kendaraanModel.size();
```

So this will give you size 0 each time cause its called sequentially. The  `onDataChange` not called yet cause its an Asynchronous call .
 You can match this scenario the when we start and new thread and its runs in its own flow(the `run()` method) then we have to wait for response .
 So what you can do is .

```
 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot != null) {

                        // Add remove your value here
                    }
        long sizeKendaraanModel = kendaraanModel.size();
                    adapter = new MenuHasilPencarianAdapter(MenuHasilPencarian.this, kendaraanModel, tanggalSewaPencarian, tanggalKembaliPencarian, jumlahKendaraanPencarian);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Also in your code i am seeing lots of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` . If you are using recycler view `notifyDataSetChanged()` is most expensive in term of just notifying the the list for changes . So make Use of .

`notifyItemRangeChanged()`

`notifyItemChanged()`

`notifyItemInserted()`

`notifyItemRemoved()`

Comment: Whats not work ? Set the adapter inside `onDataChange` and debug the your lists size inside `onDataChange` .

Comment: oh yes, i've deleted adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and put the adapter inside onDataChange. and this is work.. thankyou very much:) @ADM

Answer (score 0):

This is because You are adding value in "kendaraanModel" after Initializing Recycler 
and after adding values in "kendaraanModel"  , You have added > adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); i.e affecting the list..
So,

> if you want to check size You can check it in "OnDataChange"

Comment: i have tried that way, but it still show 0 size. @Sanjubaghla